# HTML5 Video controls shrinking on page load

Tags: html, html5-video

I need to integrate the HTML5 Video player in the page to run an MP4 video. This video is running within a carousel which on load does the slide width calculations, as the video original videos width managed through the CSS for with the `width:100%`.

The issue is when the page loads and the carousel initialises, the controls of the VIDEO do not expand full width of the video player. Once I click anywhere on the video, other than the play button, the control panel expands the full width, as it should.

**BEFORE:**
[image]

**AFTER:**
[image]

Comment: Its difficult to guide/answer without looking at the generated HTML structure after carousel initialisation. However, try to play around with `display:flex` or `display:inline-block` to the container of video tag.

Comment: Also mention the carousel library name, if any.

Comment: @ismi we are using the slick slider. The mark-up generated is the native HTML5 Video tag.

Comment: I created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hj5zsc38/) and the video controls looks fine. Try disabling all other CSS except slick CSS and debug.